# Plural nouns used as adjectives

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

*The query might return a list of selected items in a shopping cart, or posts in **active forums threads**, or whatever your web application needs to retrieve from your database.*

***active forums*** is functioning as an adjective here. It is obvious, of course. But what I can't get is why does it end in s making it plural? Could it be written like ***active forum threads***? If so, what would the difference be? And I have certainly many times come across nouns ending in s used as adjectives but never really understood the reasons why there was a particular need to make them plural instead of leaving them in their singular form.

Comment: _Active_ is an adjective. _Forums_ is not. _Active forums threads_ is a noun compound, composed of the two noun phrases _active forums_ and _threads_, and meaning _threads in/from/pertaining to active forums_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need for the plural. Most likely the writer thought the singular form, *active forum threads*, might be misinterpreted as *active threads* rather than *threads in active forums*.  But the problem is easily solved with a hyphen: *active-forum threads*.

Comment: Yes. Very few plural nouns are used attributively. Sports club; customer services manager. Though some new usages can really upset some traditionalists: childrens clothing; working mens club.

Comment: Or even Sainsburys.

Comment: And surely if there are threads that are active on a forum, then the forum itself is active. As such, there is no real ambiguity, hence the plural is indeed not needed (nor the hyphen), as you say.